# Visitor Visa for US Indian student studying in new zealand

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, new-zealand

I am Indian Student pursuing my studies in New Zealand , can i apply for a B1/B2 Visa for USA .I have a valid visa till March 2017 .Can I apply from New Zealand ,else I need to come back to my Home country

Comment: Did you ask the US consulate whether they would accept your application?

Comment: Yes, you can. See [Can I apply for US visa while I am a visitor in Canada?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/can-i-apply-for-us-visa-while-i-am-a-visitor-in-canada)